# Check checkbox when another checkbox is checked

Tags: checkbox, wix, wix3.7

Here is my WIX:

```
<Control Id="FeatureOneBox" Type="CheckBox" Property="FEATUREONE" Text="Feature One" X="30" Y="87" Height="10" Width="200" CheckBoxValue="1" />
<Control Id="FeatureTwoBox" Type="CheckBox" Property="FEATURETWO" Text="Feature Two" X="30" Y="107" Height="10" Width="200" CheckBoxValue="1" />
<Control Id="FeatureThreeBox" Type="CheckBox" Property="FEATURETHREE" Text="Feature Three" X="30" Y="107" Height="10" Width="200" CheckBoxValue="1" />
<Control Id="CoreFeatureBox" Type="CheckBox" Property="INSTALLCORE" Text="!(loc.CoreFeatureBox)" X="30" Y="147" Height="10" Width="300" CheckBoxValue="1">
    <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[FEATURETWO <> 1 AND FEATURETHREE <> 1]]></Condition>
    <Condition Action="disable">FEATURETWO = 1 OR FEATURETHREE = 1</Condition>
</Control>
```

I want to require the Core feature if either feature two or three is selected. I can do this by altering the feature condition but, it the user unchecks both of those, unchecks Core, then rechecks one of those, I don't want to install the Core feature even though its checkbox is unchecked.

How can I check `CoreFeatureBox` at the same time I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only I'd googled just a few minutes more!

[This code](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-conditionally-check-uncheck-a-checkbox-td5539262.html) is all I needed:

```
<Control 
   Id="CB1" 
   Type="CheckBox" 
   Property="myCheckboxResult" 
   CheckBoxValue="my value" 
   Text="Check the box please." 
   X="50" 
   Y="50" 
   Height="10" 
   Width="150">

   <Publish Property="myCheckboxResult2" Value="my value" Order="1">myCheckboxResult</Publish>
   <Publish Property="myCheckboxResult2" Value="{}" Order="2">NOT myCheckboxResult</Publish>
   </Control>

<Control 
   Property="myCheckboxResult2" 
   Id="CB2" 
   Type="CheckBox" 
   CheckBoxValue="my value" 
   Text="Check the box please." 
   X="50" 
   Y="70" 
   Height="10" 
   Width="150" />
```

I added the `<Publish/>` nodes under `FeatureTwoBox` and `FeatureThreeBox` and everything's working.